# Gatsby build error (webpack related maybe)

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I made a site with gatsby (npm init gatsby) and added some components and was working fine then:

I run npm run develop (after running it before fine) and get this:

```
failed Building development bundle - 13.532s
ERROR in ./.cache/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js):
Error: You must provide the URL of lib/mappings.wasm by calling SourceMapConsumer.initialize({ 'lib/mappings.wasm': ... }) before using
SourceMapConsumer

ERROR in ./.cache/polyfill-entry.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js):
Error: You must provide the URL of lib/mappings.wasm by calling SourceMapConsumer.initialize({ 'lib/mappings.wasm': ... }) before using
SourceMapConsumer
```

What causes this error and how can I fix this? I'm baffled. Tried with fresh new site and does the same thing.

I upgraded to latest version of node so maybe this has something to do with it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11):

I can confirm that downgrading to node 16 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to avoid downgrading to Node 16 by following instructions there: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/35607

I added this to my package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "source-map": "^0.8.0-beta.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map": "^0.8.0-beta.0",
    ...
```

Then I did `npm install`.

After that, I could run `npm run develop` without any issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: +1 for the only one that's the *actual* answer and not "randomly stab in the dark with major version changes on our entire stack until it might work"!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on node version 18, when downgraded to node 16.15.0 it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have version Node v16.14.2 but still have the same problem, when I upgrade **jest** to the latest in my case from 27.4.5 to **28.1.1** it fix the problem.
`npm i -d jest@latest`
if you are using typescript don't forget to upgrade also @type
`npm i -d @types/jest@latest`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.I have downgraded node to the LTS version and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue, downgraded node to 16 and its working fine now,

how to downgrade

$ npm install -g n
$ n 6.10.3

how to check version

$ node -v

Comment: This works, just need to update the version:

`$ n 16.15.0`

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

- Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- `npm install`
- `gatsby develop`

Comment: Solved same problem (with same error message) but NO `gatsby` dependency in project and `yarn` instead of `npm`. Doing: `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `nvm` to downgrade from `v18.1.0` to `v16.5.0`. The error is now gone.

More about `nvm` [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Answer (score -2):

try do delete the .cache file and then run npm run develop

Comment: Tried this. And public folder. Nothing changed, unfortunately.

Comment: I actually also get another error after doing that: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Comment: which node version you use!?

Comment: Updated to most recent so 18

Comment: Try to downgrade Node.JS to Latest Stable Version (16.14.2 LTS), it happened to me before and the solution is simply to always use the latest stable version not the current.

Comment: Just did that. Now i'm getting: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Comment: that means there is a bug somewhere in your code, check in the terminal in which file this problem show

Comment: Yes it was. I guess the main issue was the node version, then something broke. Fixed now, thank you for your help :)

Comment: you're welcome, happy you fix it :)